# How to set up environment variables in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, github, nlp, environment-variables

I wanted to run a sentence classification code from [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wwbp/empathic_reactions) but it is asking to set up conda environment and environment variables. I tried setting environment variables but it is not working. Also, I don't know to add root directory of that repository into the Python path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the instructions say to look here: https://github.com/wwbp/empathic_reactions/blob/master/activate_project_environment

```
export EMPATHY_PROJECT_ROOT="$(pwd)"
export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH"
export VECTORS="/data1/sven"
source activate emnlp18empathy
```

They assign the root of the project to be current working directory and then they append it to the PYTHONPATH

Comment: I could run the commands but while executing `run_experiments.sh` I got the following gpu related error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment.py", line 5, in <module>
    from modeling import common
  File "/home/amber/Downloads/empathic_reactions-master/modeling/common.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.layers import CuDNNGRU as GRU, CuDNNLSTM as LSTM
ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNGRU' from 'keras.layers'`

Answer (score 0):

- We can set environment variable using export ex. export DATA="SAMPLE DATA".
- [Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)    to
  set environment variable by yml file in docker container.